# TextInput problem Attempt to Invoke virtual method 'boolean abi44.com facebook has State manager

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to add in my listHeaderComponent a TextInput, but when I add this then I get this error:

[image]

When I remove the textInput, then I get no error and it works...

Code:

```
...
  function Header() {
    return (
    <View style={s.header}>
          <Text style={s.headerTitle}>{t('packet.multiple_send_title')}</Text>
          <TextInput value={value} onChangeText={(e) => setValue(e)} />
          <Button onPress={handleSendMessages} disabled={selectedUsers.length > 0 ? false : true} style={[ButtonStyles.full, s.btnSend]}>
            <Text style={s.btnSendText}>{t('packet.multiple_button_send')}</Text>
          </Button>
        </View>)
  }
  return (
    <Modalize
      ref={ref}
      modalStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, padding: 8 }}
      flatListProps={{
        data: newArr(),
        style: {
          padding: 0,
          flexGrow: 1
        },
        renderItem: renderItem,
        ListEmptyComponent: ShowTextWhenArrayIsEmpty,
        ListHeaderComponent: Header,
        keyExtractor: (item, i) => i.toString(),
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator: false,
        stickyHeaderIndices: [0],
        scrollEventThrottle: 16,
        maxToRenderPerBatch: 2,
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps: 'handled',
        initialNumToRender: 4,
        updateCellsBatchingPeriod: 200,
      }}
    />
```

Comment: I had the same issue. Unfortunately I'm still not sure what was causing this, but after upgrading all my packages, everything works. So I'm guessing it's to do with the package versions. In particular I think you'll need to upgrade `react-native` (and `expo` if you're using expo)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, Adding this to app/build.gradle worked for me:

```
dependencies {
...
implementation ("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1") {
    version {
        strictly '1.3.1'
    }
}
...
}
```

credits to: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain/issues/553#issuecomment-1253983687